# Paypal recurring extra charges on first time subscribe

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I want to add extra charge when user subscribe with recurring button first time,

Work flow is look like :
Like my plan is 10$ per month and registration fee is 5$, so the work flow is when user click on subscription button first time 15$ charge for first month 10$ is monthly fee and 5$ is for registration charge. any one suggest me what i need to do for make this happen??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set the trial amount as the registration fee($5) so that the buyer would be charged $5 once he signs up for the recurring payment and then he would undergo the regular billing pattern of $10.